# How can I share from my image gallery on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, gallery, share-menu

Do I have to install the Facebook application on CyanogenMod 7 RC3 to share on Facebook from my image gallery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you need to install the Facebook application, since it adds the option on the drop menu. Then follow this instructions after you installed it correctly:

1. Tap and hold an image
2. The screen will change to be possible to select multiple images
3. Select the images you want to post on Facebook
4. Hit Share on the bar
5. Then Facebook

Comment: I hoped I didn't have to install the application ... Thank you for great answer and editing my question...